# Importing Github Packages for GO

Tags: go, package

I am new to go language. I am trying to run my app as a service, I came across this library: https://github.com/kardianos/service

Based on an example, the package is imported as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/kardianos/service"
)
```

My concerns:

1) What happens if the author of github.com/kardianos/service decides to take down the repository, my project will be broken. How do I handle this dependency in the GO world.

Comment: The common term for addressing this is "vendoring": storing the dependencies with the project. Tools like [gvt](https://github.com/FiloSottile/gvt), gb, etc seek to solve this.